# US prices shown to customers in India

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I have a flutter app with in-app subscriptions implemented with the RevenueCat API. I have reports that some users in India are seeing prices in US dollars (and US pricing, which is different from India pricing). However, I have confirmed that some users are getting the correct Indian pricing in Rupees, so this isn't an obvious implementation problem.

I'm using the `product.priceString` attribute in the RevenueCat Flutter API to display prices.

Users having this problem are located in India, so I'm not sure why this would happen. Does the device language setting matter?

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on the store locale settings on the customer device (which may be different than the language locale). The Purchases SDK from RevenueCat uses the `getPrice()` property of `SkuDetails` on Android and the `price` of the `SKProduct` on iOS.

- SkuDetails price documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails#getprice
- SKProduct price documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct/1506094-price

It's strange that your customers would be reporting this as a problem since I'd assume they're used to seeing every other IAP in that currency as well. I looked in the Purchases SDK and there aren't any fallbacks to USD or anything that would override the device locale.

Comment: My understanding was that the price and the price locale is determined by the store association of the purchasing account, not the device locale. So someone with an account linked to the US store will always see $US since that is how they will be charged, regardless of where they are physically in the world or the locale of their device. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: That's my understanding as well - the store locale can be different than the language locale. Both can be changed regardless of the physical location of the device.

Comment: Thanks for response. I am still confused as to what the store locale setting on the customer device is and how that is set locally. I assumed that the store locale is determined by the store you sign into  and that the device has no influence on it.